# Groovy Slf4j annotation appears to be interfering with Grails built-in logging

Tags: grails, logging, log4j, slf4j

I created a Grails 2.4.5 app (`grails create-app myapp`) and added a bunch of Groovy classes under `src/groovy`. For any of those classes that needs logging, I used that [`@Slf4j` annotation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/util/logging/Slf4j.html) like so:

```
package com.example.myapp

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class MyObject {
    def doSomething() {
        log.info('I'm going to do something now.')
    }
}
```

Ditto for Grails-generated classes, such as controllers and services (that is, I'm using the `@Slf4j` annotation for *everything*). I'm finally ready to run `myapp` locally (`grails run-app` and when I do, I don't see any of my SLF4J statements logging (regardless of the log level).

Here's my logging configuration from `Config.groovy`:

```
log4j.main = {
    console name: "stdout", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")

    info  'com.example.myapp' // I'm hoping this is a wildcard that actually
                              // means 'com.example.myapp.*'

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter',
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

I understand that Grails uses log4j, but figured Grails ships with its own SLF4J binding so these `@Slf4j` annotations should work. I tried putting `'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'` on my compile path, but that doesn't work either (and produces SLF4J errors complaining about multiple bindings being on the classpath; which confirms my theory that Grails ships with its own SLF4J binding).

**What do I need to do to get logging working here?** Here's what I need:

- I need to configure logging for all the packages/classes under `com.me.myapp`, and it would be great if I could provide some kind of wildcard like `com.me.myapp.*` inside my log4j config
- Any Groovy classes using the `@Slf4j` annotation, defined inside my Grails app (`myapp`), or defined inside 3rd party JARs, must have their logging honored

**Please note:** Outside of Grails I absolutely *adore* logback. But in my experience I have found the Grails Logback plugin to be badly broken, and so I am not interested in switching from log4j -> logback inside a Grails app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that `info  'com.example.myapp'` is essentially a wildcard for  `com.example.myapp.*`, so that should work. I've found that when logging doesn't work as expected and the name of the logger might be wrong, adding a println statement for the logger name usually clears up what's misconfigured. So for example in a controller or service, just add

```
println "logger name for ${getClass().name} is $log.name"
```

and look in the console for that message after calling that controller action or service method.